# Eclipse code formatter requires re-import after Eclipse restart

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt, code-formatting

Every time after re-starting Eclipse, my custom code formatter profile fails to format my code. To fix it I need to re-import the code formatter profile and apply. The formatter then works until Eclipse is restarted again.
Is this some setting somewhere in Eclipse or is it a bug ?
Can it be that there is some residual setting in the xml format file from a previous version that is confusing the newer eclipse version that I am currently using ?

I am using Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers, Version: 2020-03 (4.15.0), Build id: 20200313-1211, OS: Windows 10, v.10.0, x86_64 / win32 , Java version: 1.8.0_171

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After futher investigation I found that the formatting profile re-appeared after I removed it from eclipse so I removed the xml file containing the formatting profile. This removed the profile from Eclipse. I then changed the filename and imported the profile under a new name and this somehow fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had a similar issue.
I tried uninstalling "editor-config" plugin, but it was not the issue.

Your answer about the name of the profile gave me a hint:
I started from "Java Conventions [built-in]" so I named my custom profile "Java Conventions [tabs]" which was apparently problematic!
I renamed it "Java Tabs" and it seems to work like a charm again :)

I didn't need to edit xml files directly.